# Using jquery Dialog with the Validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

Is it possible to use the validation plugin in a [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html) like this?
I have a page with 2 parts , Master and detail, in the first one  I'm already using validation and is in the second one, the detail part, which is very similar to the example I mentioned above , where I'd like to use the validation plugin, but if it is not possible, would you mind telling me how I can allow only positive numbers (integers and decimals) ?

***EDITED

I've just found this regular expression: /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:.\d+)?$/
,but it allows positive and negatives.What changes do I have to make to allow only positive numbers??

Comment: You do **not** need a regex to validate numbers.

Comment: @Matt. I know that, but I'm trying to use the checkRegexp function , that's why I need the regular expression.

Comment: @eddy: I edited my answer w/r/t the regex. I'm still not sure why you're using `checkRegexp()` to validate a number though. You can just combine [`number()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number) and [`min()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/min#value).

Comment: @Matt:Of course I can use those functions. Actually, I'm already using them in my Master form, but it's just that I have no idea how to validate more than one form, specially if one of them is a dialog

Comment: @Matt:I'll be very thankful ,if you could give me some guidance on how to do it

Comment: @eddy: I don't really understand what you need. What code do you have so far? What about it doesn't work for you, and in what way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible. You just need to programmatically trigger form validation when the dialog is closed, and prevent it from being closed if validation fails:

```
var valid = $("#myform").validate().form();
if (valid)
{
    // allow the dialog to be closed
}
else
{
    // keep the dialog open
}
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form

In fact, the demo you linked uses (custom) validation. Have a look at the JS source - actual validation logic aside, it's not too different from what your code will do.

---

You should just need to remove the first `-?` to make that regex allow only positive numbers:

```
/^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:.\d+)?$/
```

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to do this: $("#MaterForm").validate() ; $("#DialogForm").validate() ; ?? I'm not sure :(

Comment: @eddy: what do you mean, _"is it possible"_? Sure, you can validate multiple forms programmatically - but that's not what that code does. What exactly are you trying to do? What hasn't worked, and in what way?